# Scala Converting Each Array Element to String and Splitting

Tags: arrays, scala

I have an array loaded in, and been playing around in the REPL but can't seem to get this to work.

My array looks like this:

```
record_id|string|FALSE|1|
offer_id|decimal|FALSE|1|1,1
decision_id|decimal|FALSE|1|1,1
offer_type_cd|integer|FALSE|1|1,1
promo_id|decimal|FALSE|1|1,1
pymt_method_type_cd|decimal|FALSE|1|1,1
cs_result_id|decimal|FALSE|1|1,1
cs_result_usage_type_cd|decimal|FALSE|1|1,1
rate_index_type_cd|decimal|FALSE|1|1,1
sub_product_id|decimal|FALSE|1|1,1
campaign_id|decimal|FALSE|1|1,1
```

When I run my command:

```
for(i <- 0 until schema.length){  
    val convert = schema(i).toString; 
    convert.split('|').drop(2); 
    println(convert);
}
```

It won't drop anything. It also is not splitting it on the `|`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are immutable, and so `split` and `drop` don't mutate the string - they return a new one.

You need to capture the result in a new `val`

```
val split = convert.split('|').drop(2); 
println(split.mkString(" "));
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting a print out of just this:[Ljava.lang.String;@196f5636
[Ljava.lang.String;@5c850045
[Ljava.lang.String;@1fd4e177
[Ljava.lang.String;@511e5bf4 etc, why is that happening with the new val being created?

Comment: @theMadKing What is the expected output?

Comment: I was actually going to use .dropRight(2) and remove the 2 right peices of information between the delimiter

Comment: @theMadKing that's because `split` is an array of strings, e.g. `Array(FALSE, 1)`. You might want to `println(split.mkString(" "))` instead to make it easier to visualize

Answer (score 0):

Consider also defining a lambda function for mapping each item in the array, where intermediate results are passed on with the function,

```
val res = schema.map(s => s.toString.split('|').drop(2))
```